# Deming Regression MCR package

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am using the "mcr" package for deming regression. When i try to use the functions

```
mc.analytical.ci()
mc.bootstrap()
```

i get an errer saying "could not find function "(one of the two functions above)" "
But I don't have any trouble using other functions, like

```
plotDifference()
```

Comment: I don't know if it is useful information, but I am using a mac computer

Comment: At a first guess, these 2 functions are not supposed to be directly called by the user, but only through `mcreg`.

Answer (score 0):

Stangely they are not available, but the manual don't tell anything about not using them.

Anyway you can use them as:

```
mcr:::mc.analytical.ci()
```